# Magento error - "Can't connect to MySQL server"

Tags: php, mysql, magento

In Magento, when I click `System->Magento Connent->Magento Connect Manager` it shows the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.122' (111)

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Check for hostname may be localhost

Comment: Yes am change host in local.xml. its working now. Thanks.

Comment: As an aside - if you're running this on a Windows dev box (e.g. via XAMPP) it might be better to use the local loopback IP; *127.0.0.1* - Windows can run into some wonderful resolution issues with *localhost* making the whole thing run slower than treacle (and Magento is slow enough as it is).

Answer (score 0):

Try to flush cache from backend or delete /var/cache/*